# SOQL - PermissionAssignmentSet

Tags: soql

This works:

```
SELECT Label, PermissionsTransferAnyLead,
(SELECT SobjectType, PermissionsRead FROM ObjectPerms),
(SELECT SobjectType, Field, PermissionsRead FROM FieldPerms)
FROM PermissionSet
```

I know need the Assignee.Name from PermissionSetAssignment. I see that it has a relationship with `PermissionSet` based on [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_permissionset.htm)

I am however not able to use it as a inner select. `ObjectPermissions` is used as `ObjectPerms` in the inner select. Similarly is there an alias? Is it possible for me to use a single SOQL statement to get information from `FieldPermissions`, `ObjectPermissions` and `PermissionSetAssignment`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use **Assignments**. The below query works:

```
Select Id, (Select Id, PermissionSetId, AssigneeId, 
Assignee.FirstName, Assignee.LastName, 
SystemModstamp From Assignments) 
From PermissionSet p
```

[image]

Comment: help...  your original example query works, but it fails if I swap out "permissionSet p" for "User U".  I would like to get a data about Users and permissionSets, including Users that have zero permissionSets.  Can you show an example?

Comment: ...got it.  Needed to change the inner FROM to 'permissionSetAssignments'.  Eg:
`Select Id, (Select Id  
 From PermissionSetAssignments 
  ) 
From User p`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to Eclipse, you can get `ChildRelationship` data programmatically through `Execute Anonymous`:

```
DescribeSObjectResult describe = SObjectType.permissionSetType;
for (ChildRelationship relationship : describe.getChildRelationships())
{
    if (relationship.getChildSObject() == PermissionSetAssignment.sObjectType)
        system.debug('PermissionSetAssignment: ' + relationship.getRelationshipName());
    if (relationship.getChildSObject() == ObjectPermissions.sObjectType)
        system.debug('ObjectPermissions: ' + relationship.getRelationshipName());
}
```